# What compounds do Nor1 and Nor2 citalopram refer to?

Tags: nomenclature, drugs

In [Goodman and Gilman's The Pharmacological Basis of Therapeutics 12th Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071624422) pg. 406, two drugs, nor<sub>1</sub>-citalopram and nor<sub>2</sub>-citalopram are referred to but I have no idea what they are. Could somebody tell me a more commonly used name of these drugs or their IUPAC names if common names do not exist. Also please show me what exactly the nor<sub>1</sub> and nor<sub>2</sub> refers to. I'm guessing there's methyl groups missing in them at different positions because I know that norpethidine (or normeperidine) refers to the N-demethylated metabolite of pethidine (or meperidine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those names are referring to [desmethylcitalopram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desmethylcitalopram) and [didesmethylcitalopram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didesmethylcitalopram), which, as you correctly predicted, are the *N*-demethylated and *N*-didemethylated metabolites of citalopram. Per IUPAC conventions, the nor- prefix is used to refer to any structural derivative of some parent compound in which a single carbon and (possibly) its hydrogens have been replaced (typically by a hydrogen, but not exclusively). See the [relevant Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nor-) on the prefix for more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I saw these pages on wikipedia and I had my suspicions but I wasn't certain so thanks for confirming that.